# Call stored procedure in select statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I tried to write a recursive function, which is not possible. (I'm trying to check if a given row has a given ancestor somewhere in its chain). So, i wrote this check as a procedure instead. But I can't call a procedure within a select statement.

What's the solution for such a case?

Comment: What version of JPA are you using?

Comment: @Asgar. Nowhere in the question/tags does it say that OP's using Java

Comment: Please share your procedure you created and the error you are getting.

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?  only interested in ancestors not descendents?

Comment: #1. MySQL does not support recursive stored functions. #2. MySQL does not allow to use stored procedure output as query datasource. Solution: Integrate your query into stored procedure which calls recursive stored procedure which stores the result of its work in any session-specific object - user-defined variable or temporary table.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a recursive CTE query instead of a stored function? See [Recursive Common Table Expression Examples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive-examples).

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution.
it's possible to use a function which internally calls a procedure

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).